# iPhone Sdk: [MobileOfferViewController _shouldUseKeyWindowStack]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak, so i tried to debug with nszombie....

And NSZombie printed this:

```m
-[MobileOfferViewController _shouldUseKeyWindowStack]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6307580
```

So my question: what is the method: `shouldUseKeyWindowStack`??

Found nothing on Google....

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

I fought with a similar error for quite some time.  Best I can tell, `_shouldUseKeyWindowStack` is an internal UIResponder method that showed up in iOS 4.0 (I assume related to multitasking somehow).

However, the real error with this type of thing is usually a memory access error (too many releases on an object, or a threading error).  In my case, it was a threading error - specifically, trying to update the UI (show a UIAlert) in a background thread.  I ended up wrapping the code that was causing the crash in it's own method and then calling `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]` to work around the crash.